# How does H2o handles missing values in DRF?

Tags: random-forest, missing-data, h2o

Just wanted to confirm that the h2o's implementation of RF (DRF) handles the missing values for both categorical and numerical features the same i.e., as a separate category?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/gbm-faq/missing_values.html

> This means that missing numeric, categorical, or unseen categorical values are turned into NAs.

(The Random Forest FAQ isn't that explicit or detailed, but DRF and GBM treat missing values the same, e.g. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52976032/841830 )